# Authentication request with kerberos

Tags: authentication, kerberos, windows-authentication, sccm

I'm working on accessing Microsoft Endpoint Configuration Manager (SCCM)and it uses Kerberos authentication. I need help in understanding how can I generate the Authorization header (negotiate) with the given username and password which have access to the SCCM server.

Comment: Can you be more specific so I can point you in a direction?  What do you need to know to help you get started in 1 question.

Comment: @MattAndruff If I have to send an HTTP GET request to an endpoint using Kerberos auth, what should be flow and headers? How do I get the required values for Kerberos headers so that I can successfully retrieve data?

Comment: You don't do anything, you don't write headers, you find a library that does the work for you.  Believe it or not Kerberos doesn't actually ever pass your password to the server during login.  This is not something you hand code.  You need to create a principle(user) to access the endpoint and find a library to do the kerberos work for you.  (If you are using java look into Jaas it's a very simple way to use kerberos.)

Comment: @MattAndruff Thanks for the pointers, could you please share if you are aware of any such library for JS? That would be really helpful.